# Itertool combination dumping

Tags: python, pickle, python-itertools

I'm looking for a solution to store itertools.combination on file because with combination of 6 number my pc kill the process when swap is full.

I read about klepto but I don't know how to store the list.

```
numbers = np.arange(1,110)  
combinations(numbers, 6))
```

Comment: In general, serializing an iterator is probably something you want to avoid

Comment: 110 choose 6 is 2,141,851,635 combinations, right? That's an awful lot to write to disk,

Comment: To avoid saving 2 billion+ combinations explicitly in the file, you should instead store something that represents them in a compact abstract way.

Comment: Yes but I need store all the combinations for further analysis. I've more disk space than memory ;)

Comment: if you want to store just a list, use array (https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) if list items are of same type. Otherwise use struct (https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html). If you want to restart iterator, you should to know formula of generating values and to store its intermediate state (a step)

Comment: Give some more thought to how you need to access them. For example, to sum a series of numbers, you don't need to have them all in memory or on disk at once; you only need the *next* number, which you can discard after you've added that to a running total.

Comment: I want to store the entire list of arrays, all the combination, i have to confront and and minimize the list but I need the results stored, the eduction will be not so drastic, maybe 20-25% but the result will still be a very large array that can't be stored in memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

with open('file', 'w') as f:
    numbers = np.arange(1,110)
    for i in combinations(numbers, 6):
        print(i, file=f)
```

This saves the output line by line, so not much memory is needed.

Comment: Any idea how big that file will be or how long it will take to save?

Comment: If my math is not completely off it should be around 30-60min with below 66GB.

Comment: You should ditch `numpy` for this, it will be unnecessarily slow

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The answer provided solved my problem that basically was to write to disk all the combinations. Nothing else sorry